# Selenium tests won't run in jenkins using FirefoxDriver, runs fine on local desktop

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to get my selenium tests running in Jenkins, but facing below issue. Tests run just fine in on my local computer when run using maven test or intellij.

Firefox 39 x64
Selenium 2.46.0
SeleniumHQ plugin (autoupdating, so should be latest version)

According to this, Xvfb server should be running

```
Xvfb starting$ Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x758x16 -fbdir /data/jenkins/xvfb-64-6044594236651529452.fbdir
```

Where is the problem? I can't figure it out after 2 days of searching internet and trying just about everything I've found.

Source:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
        String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
        baseUrl = BASE_URL;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    1436973591335   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1436973591336   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"fxdriver@googlecode.com","syncGUID":"NERSGr4g-th8","location":"app-profile","version":"2.46.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox WebDriver","description":"WebDriver implementation for Firefox","creator":"Simon Stewart","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/tmp/anonymous134216584359310857webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1436973590000,"updateDate":1436973590000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":8440790,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"66.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false}
    1436973591336   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1436973591338   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
    1436973591340   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
    1436973591340   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1436973591340   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1436973591340   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"oj50TlNJya_g","location":"app-global","version":"39.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/data/jenkins/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/Firefox/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1435710843000,"updateDate":1435710843000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":3169,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"39.0","maxVersion":"39.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
    1436973591340   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1436973591341   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1436973591341   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1436973591341   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1436973591345   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1436973591346   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1436973591346   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1436973591346   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1436973591346   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1436973591346   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1436973591350   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1436973591351   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1436973591351   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1436973591351   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1436973591351   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1436973591352   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1436973591586   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:120)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:275)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at cz.bsc.g6.mbs.pda.selenium.ide.Base.setUp(Base.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the DISPLAY environment variable? This will need to be set in order for the tests to be executed in headless mode.

We use the Xvnc Jenkins plugin to assign the variable a random number in the job setup:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin

Here's also a really useful guide to getting headless tests up and running using Jenkins:

http://blog.dahanne.net/2011/07/18/run-ui-tests-on-a-headless-jenkins-hudson-continuous-integration-server-running-ubuntu/